# Extracting data from an XML and placing it in a HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I am not a coding expert so need your help.

I have a XML file as a string variable stored in the `$(xml)` variable shown below in code.

I am able to parse this XML file and extract the data row wise but the problem is that the extracted data has no space present in it between the two values.

Also, I want this extracted data to be put in tabular format of **5x5**. Using JavaScript/jQuery

Thanks

```
var xmlString = $(xml).find("table_cell_value1,table_cell_value2,table_cell_value3,table_cell_value4,table_cell_value5").text();
```

Comment: Plz elaborate.What you have in html and how you are extracting.You can use jsfiddle.

Comment: what's present in your xmlString after parsing xml?

Comment: pls specify how the xml values are extracted..

Comment: Its just extracting from a static HTML table, forming xml and then extracting back from the xml to form the same table again. Can anyone please help me by posting a working fiddle of that. Thanks

Comment: you will have to define some sort of structure of your data, like each column will have 3 characters of data, only then you will be able to fill the table appropriately, otherwise it is impossible to get the column data from that ABCDEFGHIJKL

Comment: wait, you can get the column values separately. It shouldn't be a problem now

Comment: Abdul I have just inserted the dummy data in the table. The data will be of string type of varying length between 8-20 characters.

Comment: got it, wait a minute

Comment: The first alert shows the generated xml. The second alert shows the content extracted back from that generated xml. I want the extracted content to be placed in a table of 5x5 from which it was extracted earlier. 
http://jsfiddle.net/qorwopw3/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright now, going step by step.. first up your xml format, it should be in the following format (which it already is i guess):

```
<root>
    <asset>
        <name></name>
        ...
    </asset>
    <asset>
        <name></name>
        ...
    </asset>
</root>
```

In my solution, i have created this XML like:

```
    var xml = "";
    xml+= '<?xml version= "1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
    xml+= '<root>';
        xml += '<asset>';    
        var index1 = "111";
        xml += '<name>'+index1+'';
        xml += '</name>';

        var index2 = '111';
        xml += '<company>'+index2+'';
        xml += '</company>';

        var index3 = '111'
        xml += '<country>'+index3+'';
        xml += '</country>';

        var index4 = '111'
        xml += '<fname>'+index4+'';
        xml += '</fname>';

        var index5 = '111';
        xml += '<lname>'+index5+'';
        xml += '</lname>';
        xml += '</asset>';

        xml += '<asset>';    
        var index1 = "222";
        xml += '<name>'+index1+'';
        xml += '</name>';

        var index2 = '222';
        xml += '<company>'+index2+'';
        xml += '</company>';

        var index3 = '222'
        xml += '<country>'+index3+'';
        xml += '</country>';

        var index4 = '222'
        xml += '<fname>'+index4+'';
        xml += '</fname>';

        var index5 = '222';
        xml += '<lname>'+index5+'';
        xml += '</lname>';
        xml += '</asset>';      
    xml+= '</root>';
```

So it has two records, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111 and 222, 222, 222, 222, 222.

Next up is the XML Parser which is going to parse this XML for you and populate the table. I have used the DOMParser.

Outer loop will be till the length of the asset tags (your records), then in that loop i made the rows and added them to the table...

```
for(var i=0; i<xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("asset").length; i++) {
    html += '<tr><td>' + xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("asset")[i].childNodes[0].innerHTML + '</td><td>' + xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("asset")[i].childNodes[1].innerHTML + '</td><td>' + xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("asset")[i].childNodes[2].innerHTML + '</td><td>' + xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("asset")[i].childNodes[3].innerHTML + '</td><td>' + xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("asset")[i].childNodes[4].innerHTML + '</td></tr>';
    //row construction ends here
    $('#tb tr:last').after(html); //adding row to the table.
    html = "";  //emptying this string after one row has been added to avoid multiple rows to be added in next iteration       
}
```

The above loop will run 2 times (as my xml had 2 records) and will populate the table row by row, for the first row: 111, 111, 111, 111, 111 and for the second row: 222, 222, 222, 222, 222.

**[See the working DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/qorwopw3/5/)**

If you have any confusion, feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks Abdul. But I want the XML to be created in that same way. Please edit your answer. No. I don't want the table creation to be dynamic.

Comment: you want to create xml from what? where did the values will come from?

Comment: They are just static values feeded by me. Nothing dynamic.

Comment: then i have already created xml string from static values? you want it to be done in a loop or something?

Comment: Thanks a lot Abdul. I sorted out that problem. Extending this same problem, if I have a table with variable no of columns where the table's id is used to uniquely identify the table. How that can be done? Any clue?